# Microsoft Script Debugger does not display any information after error

Tags: javascript, script-debugging, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to debug a Javascript error which *only* occurs in Internet Explorer.  I have Microsoft Script Debugger installed, and have used it successfully in the past.  On this error, though, I select "Yes" to do-you-want-to-debug?, and it opens up Script Debugger, which displays nothing.  Running documents window is empty, call stack is empty, as though nothing is being debugged.

Can anyone tell me what causes this?

Comment: maybe you could post what is causing the error and we could help you fix it? i know you're looking at the debugger, but it has to give you SOME info, right? or maybe not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had these sorts of issues before with the Microsoft Script Debugger but never managed to find a solution - if you have a license the script debugger inside Visual Studio 2008 is far far better.

There is an article [here](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/) about how you can use VS 2008 Express (free) as a script debugger.

Comment: I *finally* got the time to try this out, and it seems to work out well.  (I eventually found a way of debugging the original problem without using a debugger, which... well, it wasn't fun.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue with code inside a try/catch/finally block--for some reason the debugger gets confused by the finally block. Try commenting them out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I thought I would point out that this is still an issue. Microsoft plain sux. Developers are being forced to support products that are broken....this is a crime